# Prevent form submission and manually submit later inside an async submit jQuery function

Tags: javascript

Here's a basic version of what I'm trying to achieve.

Since I have some awaits in the function, I use `async`

```
$(document).on('submit', '.applicationForm', async function(e) {
    do some validation

    if (!valid) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

});
```

But the form submits in the end. 
I've even tried adding e.preventDefault() and that didn't work either.
Is this all because of the `async` bit?

Comment: Why async? just do `$(document).on('submit', '.applicationForm', function(e) {
    /* do some validation */
    if (!valid) e.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: @mplungjan I have some `await`s in the function

Answer (score 4):

Functions marked as `async` *always* return a Promise, so won't return `false`.

They also return **immediately**, so `e.preventDefault` won't work because it executes **too late**.

---

You can't wait for asyncronous code to run before cancelling the event.

Instead:

- Don't use an `async` function
- Always `e.preventDefault`
- Restart the submission (with `the_form.submit()`) if the validation passes

**or**

Do the validation as the user interacts with the form. Set a flag to valid or invalid as they go. When the submit button is clicked, check the status of the flag.

Comment: @mplungjan — Wanting to use `await` inside the function probably.

Comment: @mplungjan — The most common use case I've seen is on a signup form where "Is this username in the database already?" is a validation condition.

Answer (score 1):

An async function will automatically return a Promise, and since a promise that resolves to `false` isn't the same thing as `false`, the form will submit - only if exactly `false` is returned will the form not submit.

Always return false instead, and submit the form manually if validation passes:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.applicationForm', function(e) {
  checkValidity(this);
  return false;
});
async function checkValidity(form) {
  // do some validation
  if (valid) {
    $(this).submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, will try it.

Comment: This would result in an infinite loop